# Rails doesn't convert timezone (PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, timestamp, rails-postgresql

I have a problem with timezones and a postgresql db (Rails 3.0.4, PostgreSQL 9.0). I'm using a custom scope, in which I append some conditions, do joins etc.pp.

The problem is, that Rails don't convert the times to my local timezone.
Here is the code of the scope:

```
  scope :with_activities_within_range_in_week, lambda{ |latMin, lngMin, latMax, lngMax, date|
    select("date_trunc('day', activities.starting_at) as date,
      count(activities.id) as value
    ") \
    .within(latMin, lngMin, latMax, lngMax) \
    .joins(:activities) \
    .merge(Activity.in_week(date)) \
    .group("date") \
    .order("date")
  }
```

The within method checks for ranges, the Activity.in_week scope returns this:

```
where("activities.starting_at >= ? AND activities.starting_at < ?", start, stop)
```

And in the select statement, I want to trunc the starting_at field to day.

I'm getting the following output for the date field:

```
2011-04-07 18:48:32
2011-04-02 14:07:20
2011-04-02 14:06:49
```

Unfortunately it doesn't include the timezone. When I try to access my model through the "normal" Rails functions, it works:

```
puts Activity.first.starting_at
-> 2011-04-15 06:47:55 +0200
```

What I'm doing wrong? Hope someone can help!

thx,
tux

Comment: What type is `activities.starting_at` inside the database? And what happens if you `select starting_at from activities` from within `psql`?

Comment: The `activities.starting_at` is a `timestamp without a timezone` (stored in utc). `select starting_at from activities` returns `2011-04-15 04:47:34`, also without a timezone. But shouldn't rails convert the time to the specific timezone on the fly? With my example from my question `puts Activity.first.starting_at -> 2011-04-15 06:47:55 +0200` it works.

Comment: I found another interesting thing: When I try iterate over the results, and dump the class of my date field, I get `String`. But it should be `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. I read the documentation of postgresql, and the `date_trunc('day', activities.starting_at)` should return an `timestamp`. Why doesn't Rails convert this?

Comment: I cover the class issue below, I was writing my answer while you were making your latest comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your database is storing your timestamps in UTC (as it should). ActiveRecord is making timezone adjustments when it knows that it has a timestamp; so, when you say this:

```
puts Activity.first.starting_at
```

AR knows that `starting_at` is a timestamp so it instantiates the timestamp as an [`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone) instance and that class applies the timezone adjustment. But, when you say this:

```
select("date_trunc('day', activities.starting_at) as date ...
```

AR isn't going to parse the SQL to figure out that `date_trunc` will return a timestamp, AR doesn't even know what `date_trunc` means. AR will just see a string coming out of the database and it will hand it to you without interpretation. You are free to feed that string to `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` (or your favorite time handling class) yourself: there's nothing wrong with telling AR things that it does not and cannot know on its own.

Rails is clever but it isn't magic.

Comment: thx for your answer. That was it that I figure out by dumping the class. How would you feed the string to `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone``? Iterate through the results and convert the string?

Comment: You'll be iterating through the results anyway so you could throw the TimeWithZone stuff in there. I'm not an AR3 scope guru though so there might be a better way.