# Rails: Return from Query returns two different timestamp formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Model

```
scope :completed_at, select("(
      SELECT goals.created_at
      FROM goals
      WHERE goals.user_id = users.id
      ORDER BY goals.created_at
      LIMIT 1
    ) as completed_at
  ")
```

Controller

```
@users = User.select("email, first, last, created_at").completed_at.order("created_at ASC").limit(1).all
```

Resulting SQL Query

```
SELECT email, first, last, created_at, (
 SELECT goals.created_at
 FROM goals
 WHERE goals.user_id = users.id
 ORDER BY goals.created_at
 LIMIT 1
 ) as completed_at
 FROM "users" ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 5
```

Sample JSON Output

```
"user": {
        "completed_at": "2011-06-07 15:04:56",
        "created_at": "2010-01-01T06:00:00Z",
        "email": "user@user.com",
        "first": "Test",
        "last": "User"
    }
```

Note how created_at is coming out as UTC, but "completed_at" is coming out local time?  Any idea why or how to get them to be the same format?

Comment: Is your problem just the different formats or is it a timezone issue? If it's just the format you can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: I supposed I could do that. I guess it just seems weird to me to have to. Wondering why Rails is returning different formats... DATE_FORMAT is also MySQL-specific, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon, I'm not sure exactly how you're generating the json, but I'd fire up the console and see if I could figure out what type of datetime object you're getting for each column.

Also, are you setting Time.zone?

```
rails c
> Time.zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
> u = User.select("email, first, last, created_at").completed_at.first
> u.created_at.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
> u.completed_at.class
=> Time # (just a guess)
```

The module in AR that handles time zone conversion is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb).

One thing to note is that AR will not TZ convert any columns not in the columns_hash, i.e. your 'completed_at' column will NOT get TZ converted. I know, this seems backwards from what you're experiencing, but it may give you a clue.

Comment: > u.completed_at.class
=> String    # sadTrombone    

I guess I'll just run in_time_zone('UTC') to convert to TimeWithZone

Comment: Jon, I think this SO question is the same issue -- looks like AR won't convert the the timestamp out of postgres because it doesn't know it's a timestamp. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737504/rails-doesnt-convert-timezone-postgresql